# R apply() function issue with custom function included

Tags: r, function, apply

I have coded following function:

```
one_way_anova <- function(m, n, sample_means, sample_vars) {
  keskiarvo = 1/m*sum(sample_means)
  otosv = (sum((sample_means-keskiarvo)^2))/(m-1)
  TS = (n*otosv)/(sum(sample_vars)/m)
  parvo = 1-pf(TS, m-1, m*(n-1))
  return(parvo)
}
```

And using following data:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- matrix(rnorm(300*20), nrow=300)
sample_means <- matrix(rowMeans(dat), nrow=100)
sample_vars <- matrix(apply(dat, 1, var), nrow=100)
m <- nrow(sample_means)
n <- ncol(sample_means)
```

Now I try to use `apply` -function to calculate "parvo" with my function `one_way_anova` for dataset `sample_means` by individual rows with three samples (matrix is 100x3).
`apply(sample_means, 1, one_way_anova)`

Which gives following error
`Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : argument "sample_means" is missing, with no default`

Comment: perhaps this: `apply(sample_means, 1, function(x) one_way_anova(x, m, n, sample_vars))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your function `one_way_anova` needs multiple arguments, you need to pass all other arguments besides `sample_means` if you used `apply`.

If you want to run it over rows in `sample_means` and `sample_vars`, maybe you can try `sapply` like below

```
sapply(1:m,function(k) one_way_anova(m,n,sample_means[k,],sample_vars[k,]))
```